# Website translation not seen by Google US

Tags: php, seo, translation, poedit

My website has been translated in PHP, from french to english, thanks to Poedit.

But it is still not possible to find my website for any english key words in Google US.

Only the exact website name research works in Google US (Graffy Street), moreover the website description will appear in french.

Each french text is written like this :

```
<?php echo _('Bonjour'); ?>
```

Then the _(' ') will be automatically detected and changed by the english translation (written thanks to poedit), if needed.

The URLs are the same in french and in english. This is not recommended but it should work. The language is automatically changed thanks to the Browser language.

I have added a meta hreflang at the head of each page, to notice it to Google

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" hreflang="x-default" />
```

So, how to appear on Google US for some english key words as "drawing" or "online" ?

Google US : [Google US browser](https://www.google.com/?hl=en&gws_rd=cr)

My website, Graffy Street : http://www.graffystreet.com/

Comment: Is poedit automated translator ? https://www.seroundtable.com/google-translate-auto-content-spam-17524.html

Comment: You are never going to rank for drawing, or online. You need to rethink your seo. Read this http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.co.uk/en/uk/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your hreflang tag is incorrectly declared, there is no language declaration and you have a sparse amount of content on the site. You need to fix the language declarations and the multi-lingual relationship between your FR and EN versions using the hreflang tag properly.

Even after that, as @user29671 pointed out, it's ridiculously ambitious to aim for "drawing" or "online" as your target keywords!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advices.

Poedit is a non-automatic translator. I have translated all the texts of the website by myself.

I finally changed the URLs, with subdomains. I now have a http://www.en-us.graffystreet.com/ URL pointing to the single english version.

I also have added two lines to my header, instead of x-default :

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo 'http://www.en-us.graffystreet.com'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" hreflang="en" />

<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo 'http://www.graffystreet.com'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" hreflang="fr" />
```

I think Google will notice the new english version now, because I did exactly what they adviced here :

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en